# Teamcity constantly rebuilding a pull request even though the last build failed and there have been no further commits

Tags: github, continuous-integration, teamcity, pull-request

I have TeamCity set up to build Github pull requests as per these instructions: http://blog.jetbrains.com/teamcity/2013/02/automatically-building-pull-requests-from-github-with-teamcity/

I have added a VCS build trigger so that TeamCity polls Github looking for changes. This has no special settings enabled.

My build involves a shell script to set up dependencies and an Ant script to run PHPUnit. Right now, the Ant script fails (tests don't pass) with exit code 1. The build shows as a fail, and that should be that. However, every time the VCS build trigger looks for changes, it seems to find some, even though there have been no more commits. It then runs yet another build of the same merge commit and keeps repeating the build endlessly.

Why is it constantly thinking that there are changes when there are not?

Comment: Did you mange to solve this one? I am running into the same problem. It looks like it's to do with the Github plugin but have no idea why.

Comment: Yes, I did. It was because I was checking out to a non-standard directory, which was based on an environment variable. When I set it to check out to the default location, it worked OK.

Comment: In my case it was the build trigger settings. I had "Trigger a build on each check-in" ticked. It seems that changes to the pull request status were mistaken for check-ins causing teamcity to build infinitely. Un-ticking the option solved the problem.